# Tell Typescript not to compile sibling folder

Tags: typescript, tsc

My project structure is like so:

```
development
|__Shareable component library
|__Shareable component library
|__Main app
etc.
```

Each project has its own `dist` directory in which the compiled Javascript is produced, using the `outDir` option in **tsconfig.json**.

I want to be able to import components in one project from another like so:

```
import { MyComponent from 'ShareableComponentsLib1' };
```

So I'm using the `paths` option is **tsconfig** like so:

```
"paths": {
  "ShareableComponentsLib1": ["../shareable-components1/path/to/component"]
}
```

But when I run tsc, it creates a directory for each component library in `paths`. This isn't what I want, as I have SystemJs set up to take the component from the compiled Javascript in each project's own `dist` directory. So for instance, I want `Main app`'s `dist` directory to only include the compiled Javascript for `Main app`, and when SystemJs sees `ShareableComponentsLib1` it knows to look in the siblinb directory's `dist` directory.

Is there a way to tell Typescript to recognize things like `import { MyComponent from 'ShareableComponentsLib1' };` without having it try to compile them?

Comment: If you use `outDir` then `../shareable-components1/path/to/component` should only contain `.js` files (and maybe `.d.ts` and `.js.map` files). So how could it compile that?

Comment: It's compiling the `.ts`  files from `../shareable-components1/path/to/component` and placing them in `dist/shareable-components1/path/to/component`.